# Installing Tensorflow when Python 3.9 is installed on Path?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

2 Versions of Python 3.9 and 3.8.6 are installed on Win 10. I Also want Tensorflow installed. But Pip recognises only Py 3.9 and hence does not installs tf locally. Is there a way out for this.

Comment: source the path to the bin of python

Comment: which python do you want to install tensorflow for?

Comment: `py -3.8 -m pip install tensorflow`

Comment: @hoefling It works, thank you

Comment: use this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447565/installing-tensorflow-when-python-3-9-is-installed-on-path

Answer (score 12):

Try this command

`python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: I suppose it will use ```python3.9```, isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

This work with my python 3.9

Comment: This appears to be for Mac OS. I got this error on Fedora:

`ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: invalid ELF header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

Comment: @RobbieTheK that's odd.. seems to work on my Windows system.

Answer (score 4):

The following command should be work for python version 3.9:
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 2):

For dealing with multiple Python Versions it is highly recommended to use virtual environments. It makes live much easier. For a detailed guide how to set them up read this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-python-versions-and-virtual-environments-venv-pyenv-pyvenv-a29fb00c296f/

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
python3.8 -m pip install tensorflow
```

I think pip uses the latest python version, so you have to tell pip to install with python3.8 or use the beta version of tensorflow:

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

Comment: the last command worked for me because I was using Python 3.9 and will only work with the most recent version/builds of tensorflow (tf-nightly) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change you're Environment variable from `python 3.9` to `python 3.8.6` .

1.search for `environment variables` in your pc see the pic --->.
[Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK9uq.png)

2.Now select `environment variables` option see pic --->.
[click on option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTCZ9.jpg)

3. Now `edit` the path of wanted python see pic --->.
   [Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDyOQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your system is defaulting to python 3.9 because it is higher up in the system path list, so it is seen first.
search for environment variable in windows then click on **environment variable**. Then under **system variable**, search for **path** and then move the **python3.8** higher up than python3.9.
Your system will now see 3.8 as default.

Answer (score 0):

I did two things to make it work.

1. After pip install tensorflow, restarted my VS Code
2. Change the interpreter from 3.9 to 3.7, so it started installing ipython relevant packages and then changed it back to 3.9.