# Why is Heroku failing to compile my python application?

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py, bots

I've downloaded this module called `guesslang` through `pip` and I've added it to my `requirements.txt` file for Heroku to download it. When I run my discord bot locally, it works with no issues. However, whenever I deploy it on Heroku, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0 (from guesslang==2.0.1->-r /tmp/build_ca38c743_/requirements.txt (line 11)) (from versions: none)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0 (from guesslang==2.0.1->-r /tmp/build_ca38c743_/requirements.txt (line 11))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here's my `requirements.txt` file:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
PyNaCl==1.3.0
dnspython==1.16.0
pandas
async-timeout==3.0.1
pip
youtube_dl
colorlog
pyjokes
howdoi
guesslang
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What python runtime are you using, for heroku?

Comment: @Ceres `python-3.9.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow doesn't run on `python-3.9x` yet, change the python version to `3.8.5` and your build will be successful.

runtime.txt

```
python-3.8.5
```

### References:

- [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447565/installing-tensorflow-when-python-3-9-is-installed-on-path)
- [tensorflow requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) - 3.5 to 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Some tutorials on YouTube are outdated. The problem here is with your `requirements.txt`. You don't need to include `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py` at the beginning of the file. And some modules like `pandas` and `async-timeout` are already installed with the python Buildpack. Finally, `pip` isn't a module, so you don't need to include that as well.

I would change:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
PyNaCl==1.3.0
dnspython==1.16.0
pandas
async-timeout==3.0.1
pip
youtube_dl
colorlog
pyjokes
howdoi
guesslang
```

to something like this:

```
PyNaCl==1.3.0
dnspython==1.16.0
youtube_dl
colorlog
pyjokes
howdoi
guesslang==2.0.1
discord.py==1.6.0
```

You should make sure that the python [Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) is added to your project.

Comment: I think he needs to include `discord.py`?

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I forgot to include `discord.py`. Thank you for reminding me :)

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, unfortunately. Here's the error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0 (from guesslang==2.0.1->-r /tmp/build_ea59db6a_/requirements.txt (line 7)) (from versions: none)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0 (from guesslang==2.0.1->-r /tmp/build_ea59db6a_/requirements.txt (line 7))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed`

Comment: Try to create a text file named `runtime.txt` in the base directory of your project and adding this in the first line: `python-3.7.0`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/yoeo/guesslang/blob/master/requirements.txt

`guesslang` has a dependency on `tensorflow==2.2.0`

You said you were using `python-3.9.2`.

https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.2.0/

If you look on the left you can see the supported Python versions are:

```
Python :: 3.5
Python :: 3.6
Python :: 3.7
Python :: 3.8
```

Python 3.9.2 is not supported. Downgrade your Python to a version listed here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version